# data structure for wildcard based strings

Tags: data-structures, tree

I have a list of strings as follows,

```
`|Country A|City A|Street A| => Foo
 |Country A|City B|Street A| => Bar
 |Country C|City B|Street B| => Gee
 |Country A|*|Street E| => Unkown`
```

Each country, city and street represent a value like Foo.

Sometimes, the Country|City|State can be a wildcard(*) and then it represents a value Unkown.

Is there a data structure that I could use to represent this input.

As a user, when I enter a country|city|street combo, I expect to get a value. If it is not there, then it returns empty.

I guess I should use some sort of tree strucutre to store this data. But I am not sure how it would be structured.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use a data structure. Try encapsulating this in a class and then creating methods that do your calculations for you. It will make things simpler for you and anyone else who works on your code if you abstract things into separate classes and perform functions/methods objects.

In this example you could create a method that does your comparison and create a class that houses country/city/state.